# Python Word2Vec: understand the trained model itself in detail

Tags: python, model, gensim, word2vec

Let me make my question clearer:

I am using python `gensim.models.Word2Vec` to train a word embedding model. Based on my understanding, the model training is in essence a machine learning issue---to train a neural network via a prediction task. For example, if I select parameters to train a skip-gram model, then the model is trained by predicting context words from target word. Once the model is well-trained, word vectors are just obtained from the model.

If my understanding is correct, so since in fact it is a machine learning process and the training goal is to perform well in the prediction task, there should be a loss function during training and the model is supposed to make the loss as low as possible. So, how to know the **model loss value** for a given set of parameters? Or is there **any other metrics** that we can know to **understand the model itself**?

Hope I have made my question clear. In a word, I **don't** want to evaluate the model by its outputs as in the Google test set http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/questions-words.txt, but I want to understand the model itself as a simple machine learning problem during its training process. Would this be possible?

Comment: To understand in simple terms word2vec is not easy: there have been papers explain papers that explained the original paper from Tomas Mikolov. The best introduction - useful as it introduce a lot of intuition, is from Chris Moody (from StichFix) at last year text by the bay. [A must see.](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjS6fycyvPLAhVIuRQKHXY5At8QtwIILDAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DvkfXBGnDplQ&usg=AFQjCNElhbnetKSLJFrtzmt2RyqUwxl7vg&sig2=NMG9XGx0w7ayalhYvo6NdA)

Comment: @Enzo thank you very much for your sharing!